# Convert from img URL to file to send via ajax to server

Tags: html, ajax, blob

I want to take an image URL entered into a text box by a user and save as a file to my server.

So far I've saved files from users like this...

```
var myFormData;
document.getElementById("fileInput").onchange = function () {

      myFormData = new FormData();
      myFormData.append('uploadFile', $("#fileInput").prop('files')[0]);

      $.ajax({
          url: '/php/uploadFile.php', 
          type: 'POST',
          processData: false, 
          contentType: false, 
          dataType : 'text',
          data: myFormData, 
          success: function(response){
          },
          error: function(response){
          }
        });
    }
};
```

But of course that only works when the user chooses via an input of type="file", and I've just learned from other SO posts that for security reasons it's impossible to programatically set the value of $("#fileInput").prop('files')[0].

So now it seems that to achieve this I need to some way convert the img I have (e.g. http://www.imageexamples.com/image1.jpg) to a file so that I can append it to my form and upload via ajax.  Does sound like the correct way to go? If so, I've been really struggling to find any examples of others doing it, so appreciate any pointers at all!

Comment: How do users upload the images using an url if I may ask? Do they input an url?(because that wouldn't be safe either) Please explain to me in short. Could you also attach the relevant HTML?

Comment: they do indeed input an URL - i.e. type, copy/paste etc into a text box that checks to see that it's an image and then hands off to server

Answer (score 0):

[SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will prevent you from downloading images from arbitrary websites with ajax.
What you should do is send the url to the server and let the server download and store the image.